# Displaying Arabic text in JavaFX application

Tags: javafx-2, arabic

I have a simple javafx application that I have created using Scene Builder 1.0, I have tested this application in both xp and win7 and the **arabic characters** displays well, but when I have tested the same application in another machines (xp and win7) the application displays arabic in disorder (from left to right) ! how can I fix this ?

JavaFX 2.1 - Netbeans 7.2 - JDK 1.7

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need to install/activate Arabic language support in windows box.
Can you type in arabic text in wordpad in that machine?

Comment: Yes the arabic package is already installed in both OS (xp & win7)

Comment: >I have a simple javafx application that I have created using Scene Builder 1.0, I have tested this application in both xp and win7 and the arabic characters displays well Then please help others, tell us how did you do this, because we all know JavaFX doesn't support RTL languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Bi-Di tests (e.g. Arabic) would be supported only in fx 3.0 (coming next year), see http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17411

Although you will be able to try it once developers builds of 3.0 will be made available, I expect it to happen soon.

Comment: But, as I have said, that I have tested the same application on another pc (xp & win7) and the text is correclty displayed !

Comment: oh did they have same FX version?

Comment: Yes the same Configuration ! that is why I have doubts if I have correctly installed my arabic packs in the new machines !? and now I'm trying to find what is the difference between the tow machines (xp in first hand and win7 in other hand).

Comment: strange, maybe there is some difference in xp and vista arabic language support